# NextAuth OAuth and securing Spring Boot backend

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, next.js, oauth-2.0, next-auth

**Context**

I am using NextJS as my frontend, and Spring Boot as my backend. For now, in my local, NextJS is being executed at http://localhost:3000 and Spring Boot at http://localhost:8080. Both of them will be deployed in GCP using Cloud Run (I am thinking about having a separate service for the frontend and backend, but I could deploy them together too).

**Requirement**

My backend has to protect its endpoints for only authenticated users (Google authenticated, I don't intend having credentials based authentication, for now).

My first question was whether I should add the OAuth client authentication in my frontend using NextAuth, or in the backend using Spring Security. I ended up choosing NextAuth in the frontend since I can easily force users to authenticate before accessing certain pages.

Now the main idea is to be able to secure all my Spring Boot endpoints for only authenticated users (there are no need for roles now, just authentication). For this part, I am thinking if it would be enough just to add a **Bearer Token** header with the "id_token" provided by Google in every request to the backend, and when the backend receives the request, in some sort of filter, extracts the token from the header and then validates (verifies) whether the JWT token is valid using [this Google library](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token?hl=es-419#using-a-google-api-client-library).

---

I wonder if this would be secure enough for this use case, but I am also worried about what would happen if the token is expired. I should obviously check for that in the backend before deciding if the request goes through or not, but I am also assuming that if the token is expired, the NextAuth with somehow force the user to re-login in the frontend, creating a new "access_token" and "id_token" for him. Is this correct?

On top of that, if I end up deploying the frontend in a Cloud Run service, and the backend in a separate Cloud Run service, to set the backend service to "internal only", which should only be accessible by the Cloud Run frontend service. That would make sense, right?

---

Do you see any problem with this? Any potential issues? Any improvements?

If I don't seem to get the basics right, please I would love some proper guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: Cloud Run uses Google OIDC Identity Tokens for authorization. You do not need to validate the tokens. Your service will not receive a request with an invalid token. Validation is handled by the GFE + IAP which sits in front of your Cloud Run app.

Comment: @JohnHanley Well, this is assuming that I set the traffic as "Internal only" and "Authentication" as mandatory (IAM) in the Cloud Run configuration right?

Comment: Regarding authorization, yes I am assuming you disabled anonymous access. Internal only does not matter. Note: IIRC the authorization header is validated even if anonymous access is enabled. That means bogus OIDC bearer tokens will not get thru even for public endpoints. At least that was true the last time I tested that feature about 2 years ago. Also, for certain token types (user versus service account) the token signature is replaced making validation impossible (to prevent impersonation by reusing tokens).

Comment: @JohnHanley But this is confusing to me, because if I don't add any kind of security in my Spring Boot app, and I publish the service as external to Cloud Run and allow anonymous access, everyone will be able to call its endpoints without having to authenticate with anything. Even if an authorization header gets automatically validated, I have to somehow let my Spring Boot application know that the request can go through because the request has been made with a valid Google OAuth token header, no?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. IIRC if the service is public and an OIDC bearer token is included with the request, the token must validate. That might have changed but was true previously. If the service is public and no bearer token is present, no validation is performed and the request goes thru. The reason for this issue is that some people implemented their own authorization strategies using the HTTP Authorization header and IAP blocked those requests because the token could not be validated with Google public keys.

Comment: If your goal is to protect one Cloud Run app so that it can only be called by another Cloud Run app, then implement OIDC Identity Tokens and enable authorization for the protected service. The caller adds the bearer token and calls the protected app. The **internal** setting you mentioned refers to apps with VPC IP addresses. Cloud Run is not part of your VPC. Therefore setting internal only will block one Cloud Run app from calling another.

Comment: There is an exception to my last comment regarding the internal setting, but that requires serverless VPC connectors.

Comment: @JohnHanley I think that what you are suggesting is to is to enable the "mandatory authentication (cloud IAM)" setting in the Cloud Run backend service, and for that service add the "allAuthenticatedUsers" as a principal. With this, I don't even need to add token related security in my Spring Boot code, right?

Comment: `allAuthenticatedUsers` means anyone with a Google account. That is almost as public as anonymous. Enable authentication, specify the service account of the other Cloud Run service, and the role of `invoker`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254299/discussion-between-xburnsed-and-john-hanley).